# Send Keys Not Working In Selenium With Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I am trying to send keys to an element but it is not working.

[Element looks like this. Unable to send keys to all three.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWRY1.png)

**Below is the code:**

> input id="creditCardNumber" name="creditCardNumber" type="tel"
>   tabindex="1" data-shortname="cc" maxlength="24" class="cc-input
>   ncss-input pt2-sm prl4-sm prl5-md pb2-sm" placeholder="Number"
>   onautocomplete="off" value=""

**I was using this to send keys:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="creditCardNumber"]').send_keys('0000')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="Number"]').send_keys('0000')
```

**Gives me an error as if element is not available, although I use a long enough `time.sleep`.**

**Error Received:**

> driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="Number"]').send_keys('0000')
>   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
>       return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 752, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 236, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 192, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@placeholder="Number"]"}
>   (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.140)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.35.528157
>   (4429ca2590d6988c0745c24c8858745aaaec01ef),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.2
>   x86_64)

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: apologies, updated.

Comment: can you paste the traceback? what exact error are you getting

Comment: updated with traceback @Satish

Comment: can you place a explicit wait before finding the element and then try again  http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: that did not work either @Satish , I tried implicit and explicit as well as sleep.time

Comment: I think it has something to do onautocomplete="off" not sure

Comment: can you check if its located under a iframe tag?

Comment: @Satish not under an iframe

Comment: Interesting, is it possible to share the website link? it should work with just driver.find_element_by_id('creditCardNumber').send_keys('0000')

Comment: https://www.nike.com/launch/t/air-force-1-low-obsidian-brilliant-orange

Comment: @Satish You have to sign up on Nike and then add the shoe, it will take you to the credit card portion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I signed up for nike to look up the creditCardNumber field, it is under an iframe tag. Switch to that iframe and then search for the element

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" class="credit-card-iframe mt1 u-full-width" src="https://paymentcc.nike.com/services?id=0971b459-934f-4c0e-bdd1-6b5808a77eb1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Code:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[class="credit-card-iframe mt1 u-full-width"]'))
driver.find_element_by_id('creditCardNumber').send_keys('0000')
```

let me know if this works